# looping with grep over several files

Tags: bash, grep

I have multiple files `/text-1.txt, /text-2.txt ... /text-20.txt`
and what I want to do is to grep for two patterns and stitch them into one file.

For example:
I have

```
 grep "Int_dogs" /text-1.txt > /text-1-dogs.txt
 grep "Int_cats" /text-1.txt> /text-1-cats.txt
cat /text-1-dogs.txt /text-1-cats.txt > /text-1-output.txt
```

I want to repeat this for all 20 files above. Is there an efficient way in `bash`/`awk`, etc. to do this ?

Comment: Does `for file in text-*.txt; do grep "Int_dogs\|Int_cats" "$file" > "${file%%.*}_output.txt"; done` provide your expected outcome?

Comment: Your pipe into grep does not make sense, since `/text-1.txt` isn't an executable program. Please post for discussing a solution for your problem at least code which is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
count=1

next () {
[[ "${count}" -lt 21 ]] && main
[[ "${count}" -eq 21 ]] && exit 0
}

main () {
file="text-${count}"
grep "Int_dogs" "${file}.txt" > "${file}-dogs.txt"
grep "Int_cats" "${file}.txt" > "${file}-cats.txt"
cat "${file}-dogs.txt" "${file}-cats.txt" > "${file}-output.txt"
count=$((count+1))
next
}

next
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has some features you seem not to be aware of:

1. `grep` can be launched on lists of files, but the output will be different:
   For a single file, the output will only contain the filtered line, like in this example:

   ```
   cat text-1.txt
   I have a cat.
   I have a dog.
   I have a canary.

   grep "cat" text-1.txt
   I have a cat.
   ```

   For multiple files, also the filename will be shown in the output: let's add another textfile:

   ```
   cat text-2.txt
   I don't have a dog.
   I don't have a cat.
   I don't have a canary.

   grep "cat" text-*.txt
   text-1.txt: I have a cat.
   text-2.txt: I don't have a cat.
   ```
2. `grep` can be extended to search for multiple patterns in files, using the `-E` switch. The patterns need to be separated using a pipe symbol:

   ```
    grep -E "cat|dog" text-1.txt
    I have a dog.
    I have a cat.
   ```
3. (summary of the previous two points + the remark that `grep -E` equals `egrep`):

   ```
    egrep "cat|dog" text-*.txt
    text-1.txt:I have a dog.
    text-1.txt:I have a cat.
    text-2.txt:I don't have a dog.
    text-2.txt:I don't have a cat.
   ```

So, in order to redirect this to an output file, you can simply say:

```
egrep "cat|dog" text-*.txt >text-1-output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `bash`.
Try this:

```bash
for i in $(seq 1 20) ;do rm -f text-${i}-output.txt ; grep -E "Int_dogs|Int_cats" text-${i}.txt >> text-${i}-output.txt ;done
```

#### Details

This one-line script does the following:

- Original files are intended to have the following name order/syntax:

  - text-<INTEGER_NUMBER>.txt - Example: `text-1.txt`, `text-2.txt`, ... `text-100.txt`.
- Creates a loop starting from 1 to <N> and <N> is the number of files you want to process.
- **Warn:** `rm -f text-${i}-output.txt` command first will be run and remove the possible outputfile (if there is any), to ensure that a fresh new output file will be only available at the end of the process.
- `grep -E "Int_dogs|Int_cats" text-${i}.txt` will try to match both strings in the original file and by `>> text-${i}-output.txt` all the matched lines will be redirected to a newly created output file with the relevant number of the original file. Example: if integer number in original file is 5 `text-5.txt`, then `text-5-output.txt` file will be created & contain the matched string lines (if any).